# What happens to spam and spammers?

Tags: discussion, spam

I've noticed recently some spam posts on EL&U. Maybe there already were before, but I've only started to notice them recently. They are true spams, i.e. some random content with a link inserted to a commercial website (for example, see [meaning of 'frame by'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15630/meaning-of-frame-by/15632#15632)).

I flag such posts, surely others do, but I wondered what happens to the bot account who posted the spam: is it effectively deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We banned that Chinese IP range a while ago -- simply flag such posts in the future.

Human entered spam is tricky.

Comment: I saw some of that as a suggested edit on SO itself just yesterday. I thought it might be spam, and thought about rejecting it as such, but I let it go since I wasn't sure.